# How can I change the naming convention of the stock camera/gallery app?

Tags: camera, gallery, htc-evo-3d

I just switched from a Droid1 to an HTC Evo 3d, and despite all the positives, one negative is sticking under my nail. On the Motorola Droid, the camera/gallery (I am not sure who is responsible for the naming of the image) had a naming convention that included a time/date stamp (i.e. 20110930122900). Unfortunately, the Evo does not use this naming convention (although all of the information is stored in the EXIF data). Having the time/date in the file name is very convenient when posting the images on my site (Squarespace editor doesn't simultaneously display EXIF) and captioning them.

- **Short of rooting the device**, is there a way to change the naming convention on the Evo 3d to include this information?
- Is there a camera app that is as fully featured as the Evo 3d stock app (although it's not amazing, I'm looking for it to have multiple filters and be compatible with the 2d/3d camera capture/display modes) that already has this naming convention or has one that can be configured?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not currently possible on the stock camera application, however there is an open ticket with the Android project team to make such an option exposed.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10561

Meanwhile you can try some custom camera applications like "Camera Folders" which allows custom file name conventions in addition to folder groupings.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.phasip.camerafolders&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5waGFzaXAuY2FtZXJhZm9sZGVycyJd

Comment: As a side note,  last night I developed a rather stupid application that you load instead of your default camera application. It then asks your default camera app to take a picture named X, where X is customizable.  It repeats that loop (asking for a new picture named X, saving picture you took with camera) until you back out.     Any way point is I would be happy to upload it for you if you cant find something on the market that works.

Comment: Hello; is this answer still up to date regarding the last version of Android (4.1) ?

Answer (score 3):

I would use [Vignette](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.neilandtheresa.NewVignette). It will let you change the naming convention in the settings. The pictures end up in your gallery so no need to go searching for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can either have new camera app which gives you in required naming convention or use filenamer and rename pictures.

Option 1: Camera 360 has this naming convention 2011-12-12-0215-4-20.jpg - https://market.android.com/details?id=vStudio.Android.Camera360

Option 2: Try this re.*(Renamer) which accepts regular expression for rename - https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dnsdojo.mokkouyou.android.renamer

Answer (score 2):

try our new app **Rename Photos**. It is an app that quickly and easily rename photo and video titles in the DCIM directory, where the Camera App stores it to the selected format.
There are two renaming formats to choose from: Standard and Expert

**Standard:**

- photos: img_DATE_TIME.jpg, dsc_SERIAL_NO.jpg 
  (e.g. **IMG_20190615_124530.jpg**, **DSC_1234.jpg**)
- videos: vid_DATE_TIME.mp4, mov_1234.mp4
  (e.g. **IMG_20190615_124530.mp4**, **MOV_1234.mp4**)

**Expert:**

- photos: DATE_TIME.jpg, SERIAL_NO.jpg (e.g. **2019-06-15_12-45-30.jpg**, **001234.jpg**)
- videos: DATE_TIME.mp4, SERIAL_NO.mp4 (e.g. **2019-06-15_12-45-30.mp4**, **001234.mp4**)
- this expert format allows better sorting, because videos will also be placed between
  photos alphabetically, not separately at the end of the directory.

Download link on Google Play:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cz.bukacek.renamephotos

Comment: This is BRILLIANT! Such a relief to get readable filenames and lexicographical order coinciding with date order.